# RecyclerView MVVM Item with CountDownTimer Scrolling Lag

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a GridLayout and in each item I am displaying a CountDownTimer. (All the data are from the Database)
But as I scroll up and down more and more, the scrolling lags. Which I suspect it is because I am calling the timer function for each item individually therefore making each item consuming a lot of memory as there are more and more items.

As I mentioned above I am using the MVVM way, so in each item's view model, I return the String using two-way data binding :

ITEM VIEWMODEL:

```
public class UpcomingProductViewModel {

private UpcomingFragment fragment;
private ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding;
public ObservableField<ProductData> productData = new ObservableField<>();
public ObservableField<String> timer = new ObservableField<>("");

public UpcomingProductViewModel(UpcomingFragment fragment, ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding, ProductData product) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.binding = binding;
    this.productData.set(product);

    if (productData.get() != null) {
        countDown(productData.get().getStart_date());
    }
}

public void countDown(String date) {

    DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    DateTime nextMeeting = Utilities.convertDate(date);

    Duration duration = new Duration(today, nextMeeting);

    new CountDownTimer(duration.getMillis(), 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.set(Utilities.formatMillisForProduct(millisUntilFinished));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timer.set("0 days 00:00:00");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

ITEM XML :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/countDownTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fontPath="fonts/futuramedium.ttf"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/general_14"
            android:text="@{viewModel.timer}"/>
```

The xml above states that I am using the two-way databinding by setting the time with the ObservableField . :

```
public ObservableField<String> timer = new ObservableField<>("");
```

I've been reading a lot of articles about my case these past few days and unluckily haven't been able to find an answer. The main problem is that each item takes up too much memory and therefore lags the whole recycler view and also lags the scrolling.

Hope you guys are able to provide an answer. 
Sorry for the long read.

ADAPTER:

```
public class UpcomingProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpcomingProductAdapter.UpcomingProductViewHolder> {

public UpcomingFragment fragment;
public ArrayList<ProductData> products = new ArrayList<>();

public UpcomingProductAdapter(UpcomingFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public void addProducts(ArrayList<ProductData> products) {
    this.products.addAll(products);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearProduct() {
    products.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public UpcomingProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(fragment.getContext()),
            R.layout.item_upcoming_product,
            parent,
            false
    );
    return new UpcomingProductViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UpcomingProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindProduct(products.get(position), position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}

class UpcomingProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding;

    UpcomingProductViewHolder(ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    void bindProduct(ProductData product, int position) {
        binding.setViewModel(new UpcomingProductViewModel(fragment, binding, product));
    }
}
```

Comment: post your adapter's code

Comment: Posted the adapter for the item already

Comment: you are calling `binding.setViewModel(new UpcomingProductViewModel(fragment, binding, product));` when binding, it creates a `new UpcomingProductViewModel` each time you scroll your recycler view - thats why your app eats a lot of memory

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: see https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/descent-into-databinding/, note `CrimeHolder` implementation